# How to read all .log files from directory

Tags: powershell

I have running .bat scripts that generate .log files in directory c:mydir and I would like to read all .log files to monitor my scripts.

The content of the .log files is pretty basic, if the script run ends with failure, in the .log file I have a string : 'Finished with errors' (fileA.log and fileB.log). If it runs successfully : Finished with NO errors (fileC.log)

The goal would be to have a POWERSHELL script returning the filename + status :

- fileA.log FAILED
- fileB.log FAILED
- fileC.log SUCCESS

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you can post any code you've already written and what the specific problem is (e.g. is there an error? something not working quite right?) you might get more responses than you will the current question which is basically asking someone to write the whole script for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a concise, PowerShell-idiomatic solution based on a single pipeline, which combines [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem), [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object), and [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string):

```
Get-ChildItem *.log | ForEach-Object {
  [pscustomobject] @{
    Name = $_.Name
    Status =
      ('FAILED', 'SUCCESS')[(Select-String -Quiet 'Finished with NO errors' $_.FullName)]
  }
}
```

This outputs *objects*, namely `[pscustomobject]` instances, one per log file, that each have a `.Name` and a `.Status` property; in the console, you should see output like the following:

```
Name      Status
----      ------
fileA.log FAILED
fileB.log FAILED
fileC.log SUCCESS
```

---

**Performance optimization:**

If your log files are *large*, [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) sensibly suggests using `Get-Content -Tail 1` (`Get-Content -Last 1`) as an optimization, under the assumption that the success marker string is always on the *last* line:

```
Get-ChildItem *.log | ForEach-Object {
  [pscustomobject] @{
    Name = $_.Name
    Status =
      ('FAILED', 'SUCCESS')[(Get-Content $_.FullName -Tail 1) -match 'Finished with NO errors']
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Get-Item File*.log | ForEach-Object {  # Get each log file
                                          $fil=$_.Name; # Hold the name of the file in variable fil
                                          foreach ($line in Get-Content $fil ) { # Loop through each line of the file
                                                                                 if ($line -eq "NO errors") { 
                         $stat="SUCCESS" # If line is "NO error" hold success/failure in variable stat
                      } 
                 else { 
                         $stat="FAILED" 
                      } Write-Output $fil" "$stat # Print the file name and status
                                             }  
                                         }
```

One liner:

```
Get-Item File*.log | ForEach-Object { $fil=$_.Name; foreach ($line in Get-Content $fil ) { if ($line -eq "NO errors") { $stat="SUCCESS" } else { $stat="FAILED" } Write-Output $fil" "$stat }  }
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.
Can we define a specific folder/directory?

Comment: Yeah. Just change Get-Item * Get-Item C:\Path\File*.log